# Calculating multi-step math in a text box. - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I would like an application that I am creating in Visual Studio 2010 to be able to calculate a multi-step math problem that has been entered by the user into one whole text box.

- ex. 3 * 55 / 7 ^ 2

The user would click a button, and the program would calculate the answer to the problem that they input. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
Dim sngAnswer As Integer
sngAnswer = Val(Me.txtInput.Text)
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll have to parse the string for the numbers and operators and do the calculation that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing included in the framework which will do this type of expression evaluation automatically.

You will likely want to use an expression parsing library to handle the math expression.  [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) and [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/) are both good options for this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I've never actually used an expression parsing library before, do you think you could provide me with a little info on how I'd use NCalc?

Comment: @Kuuchuu See: http://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=description&referringTitle=Home  If you get specific questions, you can always ask a new question here ;)